# Java - uploading to website html/js form

Tags: java, javascript, html, upload

I'm wondering if there is any way to upload files from a java program to a website that has a simple html form.

An example could look like the one on tinypic.com or bayimg.com.

Are there any Java libraries capable of performing this? Please point me in the right direction :).

Thanks.
Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Form uses just `HTTP POST/PUT` methods to upload file to server, you don't have to work/think in this case with HTML `FORM`, just do `HTTP Connection` to script and send data in required format

Read more:
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=62798
http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload
http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/httpclient/how-to-use-multipart-post-method-for-uploading.html
http://www.prasannatech.net/2009/03/java-http-post-file-upload-server.html
http://www.google.cz/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+http+post+upload